# Find value in column where running total is equal to a certain percentage

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Excel I have a list of values (in random order), where I want to figure out which values that comprise 75% of the total value; i.e. if adding the largest values together, which ones should I include in order to get to 75% of the total (largest to smallest). I would like to find the "cut-off value", i.e. the smallest number to include in the group of values (that combined sum up to 75%). However I want to do this without first sorting my data.

Consider below example, here we can see that the cutoff is at "Company 6", which corresponds to a "cut-off value" of 750.

The data I have is not sorted, hence I just want to figure out what the "cut-off value" should be, because then I know that if the amount in the row is above that number, it is part of group of values that constitute 75% of the total.

The answer can be either Excel or VBA; but I want to avoid having to sort my table first, and I want to avoid having a calculation in each row (so ideally a single formula that can calculate it).

| Row number | Amount | Percentage | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 1,000 | 12.9% | 12.9% |
| Company 2 | 950 | 12.3% | 25.2% |
| Company 3 | 900 | 11.6% | 36.8% |
| Company 4 | 850 | 11.0% | 47.7% |
| Company 5 | 800 | 10.3% | 58.1% |
| Company 6 | 750 | 9.7% | 67.7% |
| Company 7 | 700 | 9.0% | 76.8% |
| Company 8 | 650 | 8.4% | 85.2% |
| Company 9 | 600 | 7.7% | 92.9% |
| Company 10 | 550 | 7.1% | 100.0% |
| Total | 7,750 |  |  |
| 75% of total | 5,813 |  |  |

EDIT:
My initial thought was to use percentile/quartile function, however that is not giving me the expected results.
I have been trying to use a combination of percentrank, sort, sum and aggregate - but cannot figure out how to combine them, to get the result I need.

In the example I want to include Companies 1 through 6, as that summarize to 5250, hence the smallest number to include is 750. If I add Company 7 I get above the 5813 (which is where 75% is).

Comment: It's a bit confusing (although I didn't downvote it), are you saying that your real data isn't sorted by amount from largest to smallest? What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I imagine it's been downvoted as there's no code to look at. Typically, an Excel-VBA question shares some code and asks why it's not working (or why it's misbehaving). Your question appears to be more in the 'will someone do this for me?' which will regularly be downvoted or even closed. If you have already tried writing something but it doesn't work, add it to your question.

Comment: @CLR it is not necessarily VBA. But the reason I did not write what I have tried, is because none of the formulas I know can help me get the result I am looking for - that is why I came here.

Comment: I would look at sumproduct() with the Solver.

Comment: What is the result for the sample you posted? I have `5250`, `67.8%`, or `50.85%`. Otherwise, I don't know what needs to be done.

Comment: @VBasic2008 maybe it is not clear from the text, but I want to find out which values, combined, will give me 75% of the total of all values. 75% of the total is 5813. If I add Company 1 through 6 I get 5250, but if I add Company 7, I get to 5950, which is more than I need. I want to retrieve the lowest value that should be included (which is company 6 at 750).

Comment: But more importantly, OP wants the answer regardless of the order of the data and also without adding helper columns. I think that's where it becomes tricky.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I am currently on Excel 365 (desktop)

Comment: The clarity we need, is what output you want, do you want to get as close to the 75% as possible(like @SolarMike answer below that includes the lowest)? Or do you just want to go from the Highest amount to the Lowest amount till you would cross the threshold?  And do you want the list of company's, or just the total amount before you cross the threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA bubble sort - no changes to sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub calc75()

    Const PCENT = 0.75

    Dim rng, ar, ix, x As Long, z As Long, cutoff As Double
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, a As Long, b As Long
    Dim t As Double, msg As String, prev As Long, bFlag As Boolean
   
    ' company and amount
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:B11")
    ar = rng.Value2
    n = UBound(ar)
   
    ' calc cutoff
    ReDim ix(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
       ix(i) = i
       cutoff = cutoff + ar(i, 2) * PCENT
    Next

    ' bubble sort
    For a = 1 To n - 1
        For b = a + 1 To n
            ' compare col B
            If ar(ix(b), 2) > ar(ix(a), 2) Then
                z = ix(a)
                ix(a) = ix(b)
                ix(b) = z
            End If
        Next
    Next
   
    ' result
    x = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        t = t + ar(ix(i), 2)
        If t  > cutoff And Not bFlag Then
           msg = msg & vbLf & String(30, "-")
           bFlag = True
           If i > 1 Then x = i - 1
        End If
        
        msg = msg & vbLf & i & ") " & ar(ix(i), 1) _
             & Format(ar(ix(i), 2), "  0") _
             & Format(t, "  0")
   Next
   
   MsgBox msg, vbInformation, ar(x, 1) & " Cutoff=" & cutoff

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I can tweak this to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So, set this up simply as I suggested.

You can add or change the constraints as you wish to get the results you need - I chose Binary to start but you could limit to integer and to 1, 2 or 3 for example.

[image]

I included the roundup() I used as well as the sumproduct.

I used Binary as that gives a clear indication of the ones chosen, integer values will also do the same of course.

Answer (score 0):

### Smallest Value of a Running Total...

```
=LET(Data,B2:B11,Ratio,0.75,
    Sorted,SORT(Data,,-1),MaxSum,SUM(Sorted)*Ratio,
    Scanned,SCAN(0,Sorted,LAMBDA(a,b,IF((a+b)<=MaxSum,a+b,0))),
    srIndex,XMATCH(0,Scanned)-1,
Result,INDEX(Sorted,srIndex),Result)
```

[image]

```
G2:  =SORT(B2:B11,,-1)
H2:  =SUM(B2:B11)*0.75
I2:  =SCAN(0,G2#,LAMBDA(a,b,IF((a+b)<$H$2,a+b,0)))
J2:  =XMATCH(0,I2#)
K2:  =INDEX(G2#,XMATCH(0,I2#)-1)
```

- The issue that presents itself is that there could be duplicates in the Amount column when it wouldn't be possible to determine which of them is the correct result.
- If the company names are unique, an accurate way would be to return the company name.

```
=LET(rData,A2:A11,lData,B2:B11,Ratio,0.75,
    Data,HSTACK(rData,lData),Sorted,SORT(Data,2,-1),
    lSorted,TAKE(Sorted,,-1),MaxSum,SUM(lSorted)*Ratio,
    Scanned,SCAN(0,lSorted,LAMBDA(a,b,IF((a+b)<=MaxSum,a+b,0))),
    rSorted,TAKE(Sorted,,1),rIndex,XMATCH(0,Scanned)-1,
Result,INDEX(rSorted,rIndex),Result)
```

- Note that you can define a name, e.g. `GetCutOffCompany` with the following part of the `LAMBDA` version of the formula:

```
=LAMBDA(rData,lData,Ratio,LET(
    Data,HSTACK(rData,lData),Sorted,SORT(Data,2,-1),
    lSorted,TAKE(Sorted,,-1),MaxSum,SUM(lSorted)*Ratio,
    Scanned,SCAN(0,lSorted,LAMBDA(a,b,IF((a+b)<=MaxSum,a+b,0))),
    rSorted,TAKE(Sorted,,1),rIndex,XMATCH(0,Scanned)-1,
Result,INDEX(rSorted,rIndex),Result))
```

- Then you can use the name like any other Excel function anywhere in the workbook e.g.:

```
=GetCutOffCompany(A2:A11,B2:B11,0.75)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. However my version of Excel does not have Lambda (my organizations version of 365 is apparently just before the release of `Lambda`. We do have `Let` though.